# Jumbtron full image in background

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I try to do my image to be fully occupy within jumtron unfortunetly i still got no clue what i am doing wrong can you check? Its seems image is cutted somehow and looking not so good:

How it looks like now:
[image]

Code where is my jumbotron (on the end):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My Logo</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Wiredwiki App">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="custom.css">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
</head>

    <style>
    body{
        padding-top: 40px;
    }
    </style>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#my-navbar">

  <!-- Navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="my-navbar">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <a href="" class="navbar-brand">My logo</a>
            </div><!-- Navbar Header-->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">

            <!--<a href="" class="btn btn-warning navbar-btn navbar-right">Download Now</a>-->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#feedback">Feedback</a> 
                    <li><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a> 
                    <li><a href="#features">Features</a> 
                    <li><a href="#faq">Faq</a> 
                    <li><a href="#contact">ContactUs</a> 
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div><!-- End Container-->
    </nav><!-- End navbar -->

    <!-- jumbotron-->

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
        </div><!-- End container -->
    </div><!-- End jumbotron-->
```

And my custom.css where i am trying to achieve that:

```
.jumbotron
{
position: relative;
    background: #000 url("1.png") center center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

according to @potatopeelings change it looks like this:
[image]

According to @Shirin:
[image]

Comment: change background to background-image and see if it helps

Comment: Resize the image in paint, cut it down by a few pixels and see

Comment: @code - `background:` is a shorthand property and as it is written it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

With the bootstrap you are linked to, I think you need more padding at the top.

Change

> ```
> body{
>     padding-top: 40px;
> }
> ```

to

```
body{
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```

and your image will not be clipped off at the top.

For any other distortion you are seeing, you might actually want to check your image (`background-size: cover;` will stretch your image to cover the entire element, so if your image doesn't have the same aspect ratio i.e. width x height as your element, it will look skewed)

Comment: see my main post how your change makes it - still wrong

Comment: Do you have a link to the image 1.png? And how do you want it to look (could you mockup something in paint)? Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your jumbotron,

```
.jumbotron{
   background: url(1.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
   height:100%;
}
```

Comment: see my main post how your change makes it - still wrong

Answer (score 0):

ok guys i have solution on this, this is the answer:

```
.jumbotron {
    position: relative;
    background: #000 url('1 - Copy.png') center center no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 250px;
}
```

Additional question: as in custom.css i defined my own css jumbotron - but imageine that i would e.g i would defined css for table - then all tables will have this css - the question is how to ovverite table but only for specific table i want like with id i mean to not overrite it that everything which uses tables on my website would have this custom css. How to do that?